# If IE then serve this nav bar

Tags: html, if-statement, svg, cross-browser

Is there a way of having an SVG nav bar, like this one ([click](http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/index8.html)) but due to this not working if they user is using IE then another nav bar appears instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!--[if IE]><!-->
    Custom code goes here
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Comment: IE10+ should support SVG just fine

Comment: Can you target specific IE?

Comment: yes, you can do [if IE8] for example, you can even target all IE greater then or lower then by doing [if lt IE8] [if gt IE8] (note that these do not target IE8 themselves, this requires lte or gte)